# find the sum of the alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the sum of the infinite series

$$\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1\cdot 4}{12 \cdot 18 } + \frac{1\cdot 4\cdot 7}{12\cdot 18\cdot 24} - \frac{1 \cdot 4 \cdot 7\cdot 10}{12 \cdot 18 \cdot 24 \cdot 30}+...$$

I understood the answer posted in [Yahoo Answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130117063943AAOIw2S) till the last but one step:

That is how did he get: $ \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = 0 $

Other steps I understood.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What methods have you learned for summing series?  Why "DESPERATE"?

Comment: I know only the limits technique. Is this correct?                     I asked in Yahoo answers and [link]http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130117063943AAOIw2S[/link] and got the answer but I did not get how he got lim n--> inf s[n] as 0.

Comment: I am desperate because I have exams tomorrow

Comment: @experimentX: I have edited the question as u have asked. Sorry for not using latex as I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I see that u have got a good rep. I know you can help me.

Comment: @experimentX Thanks. can u help me in the last step please??

Comment: @experimentX thanks for trying. From the Yahoo answers thread, I did not get ONLY the LAST step. Others I got it. Again, thanks for trying.

Comment: I think that might be wrong. I am getting $$-\frac{\left(-8+3\ 2^{1/3} 3^{2/3}\right) \text{Gamma}\left[\frac{1}{3}\right]}{6 \text{Gamma}\left[\frac{4}{3}\right]}$$ from Mathematica

Comment: @experimentX LOL :D ... I know only limits technique. I dunno Gamma functions . :D . Thanks for trying though

Comment: @experimentX Can u check out the link which I have provided in the question? I think he has explained properly till the last but one step.

Comment: If `Table[(-1)^n Product[(3 k + 1), {k, 0, n}]/(6^(n + 1) (n + 2)!), {n, 
  0, 6}]` on mathematica then it converges to the above value I mentioned from Mathematica. Jut plugin `Sum[(-1)^n Product[(3 k + 1), {k, 0, n}]/(6^(n + 1) (n + 2)!), {n, 0, 
  Infinity}]` into mathematica.

Comment: It is related to the binomial series for $\left(1+\dfrac12\right)^{2/3}$.

Comment: @experimentX Please Please check the link which I have mentioned above. I understood whatever he did till the last but one step. I have exams tomorrow. Thats why I am persisting with you. Thanks again my friend.

Comment: @JonasMeyer How did u get that expression. If u explain it in plain words that would be sufficient. Also, if you are kind enough, please check the YA link mentioned in the question and explain to me how Glipp has got => Lim n->inf S[n] = 0 in the last step.

Comment: @user58648: Glipp's answer is wrong.  The recursive formula for the coefficients is confused with a (wrong) recursive formula for the partial sums.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Is it possible to solve the problem using limits? Because that is the only method I know to sum a series.

Comment: @user58648: The only way I know off hand is to use [Newton's binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).  I'm sure there are other ways, but I don't know what.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time

Comment: @experimentX, $\Gamma(1/3)/\Gamma(4/3) = 3$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas woops!!

Answer (score 4):

We can rewrite the series as
$$
\begin{align}
-3\sum_{n=2}^\infty\binom{2/3}{n}(1/2)^n
&=-3\left((1+1/2)^{2/3}-1-1/3\right)\\
&=4-3\ (3/2)^{2/3}
\end{align}
$$

---

**A Bit of Explanation**

By the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem), we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2/3}{n}(1/2)^n=(1+1/2)^{2/3}
$$
The first two terms are $\binom{2/3}{0}(1/2)^0=1$ and $\binom{2/3}{1}(1/2)^1=1/3$. Subtracting the first two terms yields
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\binom{2/3}{n}(1/2)^n=(1+1/2)^{2/3}-1-1/3
$$

---

**The General Term**
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{2/3}{n}(1/2)^n
&=\frac{2/3(-1/3)(-4/3)\dots(5/3-n)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n}\frac1{2^n}\\
&=\frac{2(-1)(-4)(-7)\dots(5-3n)}{6\cdot12\cdot18\cdot24\cdots(6n)}
\end{align}
$$
which is $-1/3$ of the general term of the series.

Comment: how did you write the series like that? could you add a bit more explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that

$$
\prod_{k=0}^{n}(12+6k) = 6^{n+1}(n+2)! = 3^{n+1} 2^{n+2} \frac{(n+2)!}{2}
$$

we see that the $n^{\text{th}}$ term is

$$
\begin{align*}
(-1)^n \frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(1+3k)}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(12+6k)} &= \frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{3}-k\right)}{\frac{(n+2)!}{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{n+2}} \\
&= \frac{3}{(n+2)!} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \prod_{k=0}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{3}-k\right) \cdot \frac{1}{2^{n+2}} \\
&= -\frac{3}{(n+2)!} \cdot \prod_{k=0}^{n+1}\left(\frac{2}{3}-k\right) \cdot \frac{1}{2^{n+2}} \\
&= -3 \cdot \binom{2/3}{n+2} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}.
\end{align*}
$$

Hence the value of the sum is

$$
\begin{align*}
-3 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \binom{2/3}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n} &= 4-3-3\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}-3 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \binom{2/3}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n} \\
&= 4 - 3 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2/3}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n} \\
&= 4 - 3 \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2/3}.
\end{align*}
$$